# Does the damage of the "Gem of Efficacious Toxin" stack?

Tags: diablo-iii

The [Gem of Efficacious Toxin](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/gem-of-efficacious-toxin) has the following attribute:

> Poison all enemies hit for 2000% weapon damage over 10 seconds.

Will an enemy be poisoned by 4000% if hit twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.** ([source](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Gem_of_Efficacious_Toxin))

Instead, subsequent attacks just refresh the debuff. However, debuffs from multiple players will stack with each other. It has also been [shown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pg3YQFsKIoI) that the 10 % damage buff stacks when used by several players.

Another small thing to note is that the debuff **is** applied by pet attacks, but it is not refreshed continously by dots.